# Replace line after match

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Given this file

```
$ cat foo.txt
AAA
111
BBB
222
CCC
333
```

I would like to replace the first line after `BBB` with `999`. I came up with this command

```
awk '/BBB/ {f=1; print; next} f {$1=999; f=0} 1' foo.txt
```

but I am curious to any shorter commands with either awk or sed.

Comment: Just remember that brevity isn't itself a desirable quality of software, conciseness (i.e. brevity with clarity) is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed)

```
sed '/BBB/!b;n;c999' file
```

If a line contains `BBB`, print that line and then change the following line to `999`.

`!b` negates the previous address (regexp) and breaks out of any processing, ending the sed commands, `n` prints the current line and then reads the next into the pattern space, `c` changes the current line to the string following the command.

Answer (score 6):

This is some shorter:

```
awk 'f{$0="999";f=0}/BBB/{f=1}1' file
```

`f {$0="999";f=0}` if `f` is true, set line to `999` and `f` to `0`
`/BBB/ {f=1}` if pattern match set `f` to `1`
`1` print all lines, since `1` is always true.

Comment: `1 print all lines, since 1 is always true`. In fact it is a bit longer "1 prints all lines, since it is evaluated as true and the default action for "true" in `awk` is to `{print $0}`". Also, +1, I came up with the same solution when trying to squeeze the one-liner.

Answer (score 5):

can use sed also, it's shorter

```
sed '/BBB/{n;s/.*/999/}'
```

Comment: 999/;}', missing the ; for a posix compliant ;-)

Comment: only thing I could get to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{print (f?999:$0); f=0} /BBB/{f=1}' file    
AAA
111
BBB
999
CCC
333
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/BBB/{print;getline;$0="999"}1' your_file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed 's/\(BBB\)/\1\
999/'
```

works on mac