# Changing the line after a match on Linux

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file test.txt that has entries in it such as the following:

```
a line of text
another line
asdf
vkqaoc
coeiam
cieksm
pqocqoci
xmckdow
cqpszls
etc
etc etc etc
```

I need to search for a line and change the line that comes after it.  I have come up with the following using awk that returns the line I want to change but I'm not that good with awk and I need a way to modify that line:

```
awk '/cieksm/{getline; print}' ./test.txt
pqocqoci
```

How can I modify that line using awk to say `pqocqoci-changed` or is there a better way?  Assistance greatly appreciated and thank you!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464726/replace-line-after-match/20470583#20470583) might help you.

Answer (score 3):

It's often easier to structure this sort of thing with a flag:

```
awk 'f{$0 = $0 "-changed"} 1{print} { f=/cieksm/}' test.txt
```

or (using the default rule)

```
awk 'f{$0 = $0 "-changed"} 1; { f=/cieksm/}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear (to me) the expected output

1. just print `pqocqoci-changed` to stdout?
2. print the whole file to stdout but change `pqocqoci` to
   `pqocqoci-changed`?
3. update the source file by changing `pqocqoci` to `pqocqoci-changed`?

**1:** small modification to OP's current `awk` code:

```
$ awk '/cieksm/{getline var; print var "-changed"}' ./test.txt
pqocqoci-changed
```

**2:** adding code to dump all lines to stdout

```
$ awk '{print}/cieksm/{getline var; print var "-changed"}' ./test.txt
pqocqoci-changed

a line of text
another line
asdf
vkqaoc
coeiam
cieksm
pqocqoci-changed
xmckdow
cqpszls
etc
etc etc etc
```

**3:** using `GNU awk` to update the source file:

```
$ awk -i inplace '{print}/cieksm/{getline var; print var "-changed"}' ./test.txt
$ cat ./test.txt
a line of text
another line
asdf
vkqaoc
coeiam
cieksm
pqocqoci-changed
xmckdow
cqpszls
etc
etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed '/cieksm/{n;s/.*/&-changed/}' input_file
a line of text
another line
asdf
vkqaoc
coeiam
cieksm
pqocqoci-changed
xmckdow
cqpszls
etc
etc etc etc
```

Comment: GNU sed only I think -- at least does not work on BSD sed.

Comment: Another way to represent `s/.*/&-changed/` is `s/$/-changed/`. or if `.*` represents `abc` then `cabc-changed`.